# How do ionic solution conduct?

Tags: bond, ions, conductivity

Do ionic compounds use ions to conduct? Or do they use electrons?

Also why don't they conduct in solid form and only in liquid or gaseous forms? I mean electrons can still travel in solid forms.

Do their ionic bonds break in the liquid and gaseous forms?

Thanks for answering

Comment: I am assuming you mean electricity, not heat.

Comment: yes electricity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ionic solids](http://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/States_of_Matter/Solids/Ionic_Solids) do not conduct because the atoms are typically bound too tightly to a crystal lattice for anything to function as mobile charge carriers.  Mobile charge carriers are available in metal because metals can easily change oxidation states allowing electrons to move; whereas, most ions cannot easily change state.

[Ionic liquids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_liquid) on the other hand have both mobile cations and anions which can serve as charge carriers possibly resulting in moderate conductivity.

As far as bonding the bonds in ionic liquids are constantly breaking and reforming just as in all liquids.

There are no bonds between gas particles.  Gasses are poor conductors; however, if the gas ionizes turning into plasma then the electrons are free to be charge carriers making the gas a conductor.

Comment: but why are gases poor conductors?? And do ionic compounds conduct through electrons or the ions?

Comment: Ionic compounds are either an ionic solid or an ionic liquid.  Ionic solids do not conduct.  Ionic liquids can through movement of ions.   Ionized plasma can conduct through movement of electrons.

Comment: Why are gasses poor conductors of electricity is a different question entirely. Since it is already on the physics exchange.  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38631/can-gases-conduct-electricity

Comment: Also. to be an electrical conductor means something with charge is free to move.  If no charge can move then electricity cannot conduct itself through a medium.

Comment: but if gases are ionized...can't they just conduct through ions?? What is the need of conduction through electrons?

Comment: In the classical states (solid, liquid, and gas) there is little net charge.    Ionized gas has a net charge so it is a mixture of electrons,  ions, and neutral particles.   I'm guessing, but it seems some ions would drift according to the flow of the electrons, so it may be possible to have both.  I'm do not claim to be an expert on plasma physics.

Answer (score -1):

First of all ionic compounds are not bounded by bonds they are bound by electrostatic forces of attraction. Secondly if the ionic compound is an electrolyte which generally is, the ions separate. The ions require a medium to polarise them in short to separate them liquid and gaseous mediums thus help as they cant self ionise in their solid state. Hope it helps.

Comment: I wasnt the downvote, but I do believe that it was because you said the medium polarises the molecule... which is not true it just dissolves it

Comment: Would solvates be the correct word then?